# Column Mapping of type SqlXml in SQLCLR to SQL table Xml column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml, sqlclr

I am passing in a TempTable to my SQLCLR code with the following schema

-- Schema for temp table

```
CREATE TABLE ##temp_table_configurationXml_local (
        [OrchConfigXML] [xml]
        )
```

**SQLCLR Code:**

```
       DataTable dt = new DataTable(tableToUse); // tableToUse is the temp table from SQL
       dt.Columns.Add("OrchConfigXML", typeof(SqlXml));


        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["orchConfigXML"] = xmlToUse;  // This is type of SqlXML and has valid XML in it
        dataTableToUse.Rows.Add(dr);

       // Write Data
       // auto-disposable bulk copy operation
       using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
       {
           bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = destTable;
           bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new 
           SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("OrchConfigXML", "OrchConfigXML"));
           // Bulk copy operation will drain memory so it is better to setup a batchsize.                      
           bulkCopy.BatchSize = 50000;
           bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
           conn.Close();  //Close the SQL Connection.
       }
```

While executing the SQL Script and debugging the SQLCLR code I get a error in C#/SQLCLR.

```
The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the source or destination.
```

How to Map SQLXML to SQL XML datatype.

Comment: How many columns are in the `destTable`? If just 1, then you don't need `SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping` in the first place. Also, I can't remember, but using column names for the mapping _might_ be case-sensitive, and you have "**O**rchConfigXML" when you defined the column, but "**o**rchConfigXML" in the column mapping. Also, I see where `dt` is created, but not `dataTableToUse`. Also, what are you ultimately trying to do, and why are you using `SqlBulkCopy` ?

Comment: Yes it was case sensitive.  I have updated the name to OrchConfigXML and now i get the following error
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlXml' to type 'System.String

Comment: 1) There is only one column in destTable. 
2) The text in this column will be XML and can be huge so using SQLBulkCopy, what is the alternative to use? I am happy to modify my code
3)I have updated my code in my question, I have few methods but for simplicity I merged the code in my question.

Comment: I started documenting this in an answer, and there are some new questions there. But for now, I am still unsure of why you are using `SqlBulkCopy`. Are there lots of rows in that global temp table? are you using SQLCLR to send an XML blob to a remote server without needing to create a Linked Server? That the XML can be "huge" does not indicate that it is many rows or one large document. But `SqlBulkCopy` only helps when there are lots of rows.

Comment: Abe, any update? Just curious.

Answer (score 0):

Questions:

1. How many columns are in the `destTable`? If just one, then you don't need `SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping` in the first place.

   (answer: "There is only one column in destTable" )
2. What are you ultimately trying to do, and why are you using `SqlBulkCopy`?
3. How many rows will be in `##temp_table_configurationXml_local`? If just one, then passing value in via `SqlXml` input parameter might be better.
4. Is `xmlToUse` being added, as another row, to whatever is in `##temp_table_configurationXml_local`? This seems like an odd and/or convoluted setup.

Things to try / consider:

1. I can't remember, but using column names for the mapping might be case-sensitive, and you have "**O**rchConfigXML" when you defined the column, but "**o**rchConfigXML" in the column mapping.
2. For the column definition in the `DataTable`, you might want to try using `SqlDbType.Xml` instead of `SqlXml`. `SqlXml` is used for input / output parameters, return types, and result set fields returned by SQLCLR objects.